# Time & Attendance Software

Tags: time-management

i'm searching for a good time & attendance software for my company.

requirements:

- **No Cloud**
- we need the software on our sites in europe and usa, a good support is very important.
- the software should handle different time zones and public holidays
- a good report generation

would be nice if it include an access controll software and if they or their partner provide punch devices for chips or cards

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you [BambooHR](http://www.bamboohr.com/).

**What is BambooHR?** (from [GetApp](https://www.getapp.com/hr-employee-management-software/a/bamboohr-saas-hr-software/))

BambooHR is an intuitive HR software system that simplifies usual HR tasks like attendance, time-off requests, employee benefits, contact information, trainings and certifications – all facets of the employee lifecycle, essentially. Its in-depth reporting features provide executives and managers insight into vital business indicators like employee retention and turnover rates, and certification and compliance metrics.